# Regexp for Visual Studio (2013+) to match and replace the exact same string

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to search for expressions such as

```
..., "String", "String", ...
```

and replace that with say

```
..., "String", SAMESTRING, ...
```

So the main issue is how to make sure the 2nd string is the duplicate of the 1st string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to match and replace all repeated same strings:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace myapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "\"a\", \"a\", \"b\", \"c\", \"c\", \"c\", \"d\"";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(\"[^\"]*\")(?<=\\1, \\1)", "\"SAMESTRING\"");

            Console.WriteLine(output);        
        }
    }
}
```

Input: `"a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d"`

Output: `"a", "SAMESTRING", "b", "c", "SAMESTRING", "SAMESTRING", "d"`

It matches a string in double quotes, checks with a lookbehind if that string is preceded by the same string and a comma, and if yes, replaces the repeated string with "SAMESTRING".

Comment: Cool thanks! I actually needed just the search & replace in Visual Studio, but apparently '(\"\w*\"), \1' works indeed! The \1 is the secret sauce!